# bouncing is not working in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have four nodes which is displaying as position given in data json. After dragging each node I have managed to set each node back to its given position . It works fine but the default bouncing is not working rather it is quickly set to fixed position. To give a bouncing effect into this what need to  change my code.

Please take a look example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #dfdfdf;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link.red {
    stroke: blue;
}

</style>




<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0)
    .linkDistance (200)
    .charge(0)
    .size([width, height]);

var node_psoition = [{"x":65, "y":43},{"x":365, "y":43},{"x":265, "y":243},{"x":65, "y":243}]
var datajson = {
  "nodes" : [ {"id":1,"name" : "a", "group" : 2, "x":65, "y":43 , "fixed":"TRUE"} , {"id":2,"name" : "b", "group" : 1,"x":265, "y":43, "fixed":"TRUE"}, { "id":3,"name" : "c", "group" : 1, "x":265, "y":243, "fixed":"TRUE" }, {"id":4,"name" : "d", "group" : 2,"x":65, "y":243, "fixed":"TRUE"} ],
  "links" : [{"source": 0 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 1},{"source": 0 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 1},{"source": 2 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 1},
  {"source": 2 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 1}
  ]
}


  force
      .nodes(datajson.nodes)
      .links(datajson.links)
      .start();


var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragend", dragend);


  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(datajson.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(datajson.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("class", 'bounce')
      .attr("width", 45)
      .attr("height", 45)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    var imagePath =
           "http://www.bigbiz.com/bigbiz/icons/ultimate/Comic/Comic"
           + rnd.toString() + ".gif";

    return imagePath;
});

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


   });



  function dragend(d) {

        force.stop();
        position = (d.id - 1);
        temp_x = node_psoition[position].x;
        temp_y = node_psoition[position].y;

        d.x = d.px = temp_x;
        d.y = d.py = temp_y;
        d.fixed = true;
        force.start();

  }


</script>
```

To give a bouncing effect each node what need to update my code. Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: There is no default bouncing when you set a node to fixed. When you start the force there is the force effect but it doesn't 'bounce' around a position

Comment: ok, by default it does not provide bounce effect as it has fixed position. is there any customization that can gives the bounce effect i.e. set node gravity to the fixed position  etc. so when we release force the node will set to previous position due to gravity and bounce will be there. I do not , how to set each node gravity to fixed position after releasing force. I have searched many things but did not find yet. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Even I do not know will it work or not or any other trick may work.